# Nan with Python 2.5 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, nan, python-2.5

How do I create a Nan with Python 2.5 on Windows?

`float('nan')` fails with the error `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): nan`

**Summary of the answers:** Neither `float('inf')` nor `float('nan')` works with Python 2.5 and Windows. This is a bug that was fixed in Python 2.6.

If you are using numpy, then you can use `numpy.inf` and `numpy.nan`.

If you need a workaround without numpy, then you can use an expression that overflows such as `1e1000` to get an inf, and `1e1000 / 1e1000` or `1e1000 - 1e1000` to get a nan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is dividing `inf` by itself:

```
>>> float('inf') / float('inf')
nan
```

Or in a more obscure way, which might not work across platforms (but works around that specific bug in Python 2.5 on Windows):

```
>>> 1e31337 / 1e31337
nan
>>> 1e31337 - 1e31337
nan
```

Comment: Why not just 1e1000 / 1e1000 ? The point is that 1e1000 overflows and gives inf and inf / inf is nan.

Comment: @user: 1e1337 looks better to me. I mainly added the `inf/inf` to make it clear why the second version works.

Comment: @drewk: No it does not work. Test it with Python 2.5 and Windows and you will see. But 1e1000 - 1e1000 works.

Comment: @user763305: Not having 2.5 on Windows I'll take your word for it, but that would be a bug, no?

Comment: @drewk: Yes, it's the same bug that prevents `float('nan')` from working.

Answer (score 1):

There is already an accepted answer to this question, but I *think* the following should work if you don't want to rely on overflow and have numpy installed ... (not tested as I don't have python2.5 or windows)

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.nan
nan
>>> np.inf
inf
```

Comment: It works. I tested with Python 2.5 on Windows. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your Python distribution if possible. [The behavior you listed is considered a bug.](http://trac.cython.org/cython_trac/ticket/450) (Note: [Cython](http://cython.org/) link.)

Canonically, Python is supposed to support this definition of `nan` in a cross-platform manner. This behavior appears to have been fixed in Python 2.6 and 3.0.

([Additional reading](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/#id5))

---

Of course, this works in the Linux versions of Python:

```
$ python2.4
Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep 21 2011, 19:55:41) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> float('nan')
nan

$ python2.5
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jun 26 2008, 10:20:40) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> float('nan')
nan
```

Comment: I'm not writing an app, I'm writing a library, that I will make freely available to other developers, including the poor souls that are stuck with Python 2.5.

Comment: @user763305 Then, yup, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9916007/517815) is the way to go. :)